# Checking Metal texture is valid from shader

Tags: metal

I'm using Metal 3 and have an Argument buffers with structures of Materials. Each material may have diffuse texture field `texture2d<float>  diffuseTexture;` But some materials could don't have one.

How can I check from metal shader if specific metal texture is valid (initialised from host side)? (One solution that could be is to pass additional flags isDiffuseTexture available)

But I'm looking something close to this snippet:

```
if (material.diffuseTexture)
{
    const float4 diffuseFromTex = material.diffuseTexture.sample(textureSampler, state.textureCoordinates);
    state.diffuse *= diffuseFromTex.rgb;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_null_texture` is the function you are looking for. From [Metal Shading Language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf):

> Use the following functions to determine if a texture is a null texture. If the texture is a null
> texture, is_null_texture returns true; otherwise it returns false.

So your snippet turns into:

```
if (!is_null_texture(material.diffuseTexture))
{
    const float4 diffuseFromTex = material.diffuseTexture.sample(textureSampler, state.textureCoordinates);
    state.diffuse *= diffuseFromTex.rgb;
}
```